# How to update chef server 12 to chef 14

Tags: chef-infra

StackOverflow seemed to have the most questions and answers on chef related stuff so here it goes. I have been looking around for a document on how to upgrade chef 12 to chef 14.

We currently have a server running chef 12, I need to it be chef 14 and was hoping to accomplish this via knife if possible. I have only found people asking for upgrading to version 12 and older, nothing new like 14.

What command or set of commands can I use to do this upgrade? There doesn't appear to be a chef owned doc that has the upgrade instructions from checking google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific command or process other than "install the latest version of the chef-client package on each machine". You can re-run `knife bootstrap` to do this just like at the initial install, though you'll need to manually reapply the correct name/runlist so this is rather awkward. You can also look at the `chef-client-updater` cookbook, which tries to automate this process. Most of the work of upgrading Chef versions is in making sure your cookbooks are still compatible with the new major version, which is usually mostly about solid Test Kitchen integration testing and good CI hygiene.